# Some unwanted borders are appearing on this HTML/CSS page I created

Tags: html, css

Hello to the StackOverflow community!

Last month I was working on this HTML/CSS Project for a Codecademy Intensive course. [Here is a link to the page on GitHub](https://gadget-geek.github.io/ColmarAcademy/).

Look down on the page and you will see the visible borders (in a faint, razor-thin grey color) around the items that read "Orientation date", "Our campus", and "Our guest lecture". How can I get rid of them and make the items blend in nicely with the light blue background behind it?

BTW, you can find my project files [here](https://github.com/Gadget-Geek/ColmarAcademy).

Thanks for your help.

A.L.

Comment: Sure you attended the class? *Any* browser's developer tools will easily tell you what you need to do.

Comment: lol it's literally the first property that shows when you inspect the element..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;` from your css styling for `.column-right .item {`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you meant to void the entire border

with :

```
.column-right .item {border: 0}
```

Looks good either way though